# How do you use pipe,map,filter,material autocomplete on a list of objects?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, angular-material

I am working on a project that uses Angular and Material Design and I want to use Autocomplete to let users search from a list of objects by their name attribute.

[Angular Material Autocomplete Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

I am reading a JSON file and trying to produce a list of objects that I can easily search by their name attribute.

"champion.json" has a data attribute which is a list of JSON objects that I need the "name","key" and "pic" which is a URL for the png file.

I have created a service which uses HTTPClient to get the JSON object from a static API or from my assets folder.

So far, I have tested and found that I can view the objects in the list by directly iterating through the list of objects using *ngFor, but I want to use *ngFor to display the filtered object list asynchronously. However, the list of objects doesn't show whenever I switch to "let object of filteredObjects | async", the async pipe doesn't work on the observable object list which I produce from reading the JSON file.

My theory is that I need to define/generate the filtered object list AFTER I read the json file or else I am defining my filter function incorrectly.

You can see the code on stackblitz but I am new to using it and can't even get it to work with `<mat-option *ngFor="let champ of championList" [value]="champ">` which does show up on my dev server (ng serve). I think that the material design dependency isn't installed correctly but don't know why. [My app on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u8arme)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Autocomplete was working possibly I just didn't see anything listed when I applied the filter because it has "startWith('')," so nothing was showing until I typed something.